# Как правильно протащить Window от V до VM?

Tags: c#, wpf, usb

Использую UsbHid, автор в примере создает все в View внутри класса формы, я же пытаюсь перенести код на ViewModel

Проблема в этих участках кода:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
    src.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
}
```

и

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    var handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    usb.RegisterHandle(handle);
}
```

Тут `this` формы нужен чтобы события USB обновлялись, но как это провернуть если вся инициализация USB происходит в `DataContext`?

```
namespace MyApp.View {
    public partial class MainWindowView:MetroWindow {

        public MainWindowView() {
            DataContext = new DeveloperModeViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

Код был [взят из статьи](https://adelectronics.ru/2016/11/22/usblibrary-c-usb-hid-library/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, в вашей статье на данный момент окно используется в *двух* целях: для отрисовки UI и для приёма сообщений о USB-устройствах. Первое использование соответствует V, второе — VM или даже M.

Это значит, что вам нужно разделить эту функциональность по разным окнам. В модели вы должны открыть отдельное, невидимое окно в отдельном потоке, в котором вы будете принимать нужные USB-сообщения. А обыкновенное окно использовать для целей отображения.

Теперь, чтобы создать невидимое функциональное окно с циклом сообщений, может сработать обыкновенное WPF-овское окно с `Visible = false` (не проверял). Но с большой долей вероятности вам понадобится обыкновенное нативное окно, которое придётся организовывать при помощи P/Invoke. Как это делать, лучше всего посмотреть [здесь](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.createwindowex).

Убирая лишнее из класса, получается такая заготовка:

```
IntPtr hInstance = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
WNDCLASS wndclass;

wndclass.lpfnWndProc = (WndProc)((hWnd, message, wParam, lParam) => {
    IntPtr hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;

    usb.ParseMessages(...);

    switch ((WM)message)
    {
        case WM.DESTROY:
            Win32.PostQuitMessage(0);
            return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    return Win32.DefWindowProc(hWnd, (WM)message, wParam, lParam);
});

wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
wndclass.lpszClassName = "USBHelper";

ushort regResult = Win32.RegisterClass(ref wndclass);

if (regResult == 0)
    throw new InvalidOperationExcetoon("Shouldn't happen");

IntPtr hwnd = Win32.CreateWindowEx(
    WindowStylesEx.WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    new IntPtr((int)(uint)regResult),
    "", // window caption
    WindowStyles.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, // window style
    Win32.CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial x position
    Win32.CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial y position
    Win32.CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial x size
    Win32.CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial y size
    IntPtr.Zero, // parent window handle
    IntPtr.Zero, // window menu handle
    hInstance, // program instance handle
    IntPtr.Zero); // creation parameters

if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    throw new Win32Exception(lastError);
}

// ShowWindow не нужен, чтобы окно не показывалось
// Win32.ShowWindow(hwnd, ShowWindowCommands.Normal);
// Win32.UpdateWindow(hwnd);

// цикл сообщений
MSG msg;
while (Win32.GetMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0) != 0)
{
    Win32.TranslateMessage(ref msg);
    Win32.DispatchMessage(ref msg);
}
```

P/Invoke-определения недостающих функций из класса `Win32` смотрятся на том же http://www.pinvoke.net.

Comment: Это как раз то, что мне не хотелось бы делать, выглядит очень костыльным. Но раз выхода нет, то придется делать и так

Comment: @Fangog: Проблема на самом деле в том, что USB-сообщения (которые по сути модельные штуки) доставляются окну (то есть, на UI-уровень). Это как-то неправильно. Но это проблема WinAPI, а не ваша. (Ну то есть теперь и ваша тоже, конечно.)

Comment: Зачем создавать еще одно окно, если есть `WindowInteropHelper.RegisterHandle`? Да и вопрос был не в этом, как раз с отлавливанием сообщений у автора проблем не было.

Comment: @Raider: Потому что в рамках MVVM функциональность USB-сообщений не принадлежит View. Следовательно, её **нельзя** протягивать во View. У автора проблема была, потому что VM и тем более M вовсе не имеют права знать о наличии V.

Comment: @VladD Для этого существует понятие сервиса и Dependency Injection.

Comment: @Raider: Не-а, M должна работать правильно и в отсутствие V. Инжектить V в M — это нарушать MVVM, прикрываясь DI.

Comment: @VladD Никто не говорит про инжект View в Model. Инжектится platform-specific имплементация сервиса по получению событий USB, которая, так уж решили разработчики Windows, базируется на Window Messages – но эти детали инкапсулированы, и View Model ссылку на View не получает. В результате, при переносе на другую платформу потребуется другая имплементация сервиса (это неизбежно), при этом интерфейс останется тот же. В случае с юнит тестированием, легко подставляется заглушка сервиса. В вашем же варианте код View  (невидимое окно) без стеснения используется напрямую – тупиковое решение.

Comment: @Raider: Нет, что-то не то. В вашем варианте в отсутствие V (или там при открытие нового окна, или чём-то ещё таком) вся схема перестаёт работать. Ну и вам в любом случае придётся имплементировать интерфейс, нужный для модели, во View. Или тянуть HWND главного окна через VM в M. Потому что у вас, как не скрывать этот факт за DI, используется окно от V. В моей имплементации невидимое окно **вовсе не является V**. Ну и да, эта часть модели реализует платформо-специфическую логику и тем самым платформо-специфична.

Comment: @VladD 1) Существование MVVM без View возможно только в 1 случае – юнит тестирование. 2) Рекомендую ознакомится с понятием [View Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx) в рамках MVVM. 3) HWND тянуть не нужно, проблема с закрытием главного окна тривиальная и решается в рамках сервиса. 4) Вопрос был о том, как правильно протащить View в VM – вы на него не ответили.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, у меня сработало `new Window() { Visibility = Visibility.Hidden };`, только вот проблема в том, что окно запускается на некоторое время, а после уже исчезает, как сделать его скрытым изначально? Я установил размеры в `0`, но оно все равно появляется, точней его верхняя панель

Comment: @Raider: Вы, как мне кажется, не слышите моих аргументов, и мне кажется, мы не добьёмся ничего этой дискуссией. Вы вполне можете дать альтернативный ответ, если хотите. Теперь по пунктам: 1) Это утверждение не обосновано, хуже того оно неверно. Кроме того, ваш подход не будет работать, если V будет время от времени закрывать одно окно и открывать другое/другие. Нет, MVVM-приложение не имеет права рассчитывать на любое конкретное поведение V. Как и вообще на его наличие.

Comment: @Raider:  2) View Service не имеет к вопросу никакого отношения. UI-сервис по цитированной вами статье есть UI из VM для UI-целей, а не открыть окно для помощи модели. 4) Вопрос был о правильной организации фичи в MVVM. И частью ответа является то, что использование главное окно для нужд модели противоречит MVVM. В любом случае, если вам не нравится мой ответ, вы вполне можете дать ваш альтернативный ответ.

Comment: @Fangog: Боюсь, этот временный показ не лечится :-( А если открыть невидимое WinForms-окно? С ним должно быть, по идее, проще.

Comment: @VladD Что-то получилось с `new Window() {Visibility = Visibility.Hidden,WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,Width = 0,Height = 0};`, но все равно вылезает полоска которая представляет из себя обводку окна http://image.prntscr.com/image/878e8822ef364676b2a6845ee5768162.png в моей win10 ещё ничего, но в 7 обводка очень жирная, будет уж точно заметно, пока не понял как можно скрыть её, попробую с WinForms

Comment: Лучше создам новую тему

Answer (score 0):

В рамках шаблона MVVM объект VM не может знать ничего об окне, это выходит за его зону ответственности. Правильным будет оставить получение Handle в классе окна.

А вот уже работу с UsbHid можно и вынести в VM. Кстати, зачем вам два события?

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

    ((ISomeViewModel)DataSource).Source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
}
```

Только не забудьте что присвоение любому свойству может происходить несколько раз и это надо корректно обрабатывать (т.е. надо удалить старый хук перед добавлением нового и т.п.).

---

Как альтернативу можно использовать паттерн MVP. Presenter, в отличии от ViewModel, имеет право знать о виде. Так, Presenter может подписаться на событие SourceInitialized.

Или же для повторного использования кода имеет смысл попробовать использовать [поведения (Behavior)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726531(v=expression.40).aspx):

```
<Window ...>

  <i:Behaviors>
    <ctrl:UsbHidListener ViewModel="{Binding ...}" />
  </i:Behaviors>
```

Comment: Ну, USB-события выглядят чистой моделью. И знать о них вьюхе тоже как-то нехорошо: а вдруг V вот прямо сейчас не показывается, что ж, приложению без USB-сообщений жить?